# Fetchmail using wrong SMTP sender name

Tags: linux, email-server, email

I'm trying to download e-mails from my aol.pl account but they are blocked via Spamdyke on my local mail server. It seems mails are send from my incorrect email not on this local server. How to correct this ?

```
[root@online /]# fetchmail -d0 -vk pop.aol.com
fetchmail: UWAGA: Uruchamianie jako root jest niezalecane.
fetchmail: 6.3.6 łączy się z pop.aol.com (protokół POP3) o godzinie sob 26 sty 2013 00:02:34 CET: odpytywanie rozpoczęte
Próba połączenia z 205.188.170.17/995...połączono.
fetchmail: Organizacja wystawcy: America Online Inc.
fetchmail: CommonName wystawcy: AOL Member CA
fetchmail: CommonName serwera: imap.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.aim.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.cs.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: client.imap.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.au.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.ar.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.br.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.ca.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.cl.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.de.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.fr.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.in.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.jp.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.mx.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.uk.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.aim.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.mcom.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.mcom.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.goowy.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.goowy.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.tunome.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.tunome.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.mda.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: east.us.imap.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: east.us.pop.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: alf.imap.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.angeliamail.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.angeliamail.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.csi.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.csi.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: nginx.aol.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: imap.about.me
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.about.me
fetchmail: Odcisk klucza pop.aol.com: 8F:EA:FB:4F:81:F0:94:9E:A0:06:C3:74:0B:96:7F:3D
fetchmail: POP3< +OK POP3 ready
fetchmail: POP3> CAPA
fetchmail: POP3< +OK Capability list follows
fetchmail: POP3< TOP
fetchmail: POP3< USER
fetchmail: POP3< SASL LOGIN PLAIN
fetchmail: POP3< .
fetchmail: POP3> USER someuser@aol.pl
fetchmail: POP3< +OK
fetchmail: POP3> PASS *
fetchmail: POP3< +OK server ready
fetchmail: POP3> STAT
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 1 3261
1 list dla someuser@aol.pl na pop.aol.com(3261 bajtów).
fetchmail: POP3> LIST 1
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 1 3261
fetchmail: POP3> RETR 1
fetchmail: POP3< +OK message follows
pobieram list someuser@aol.pl@nginx.mx.aol.com.aol.akadns.net:1 z 1 (3261 bajtów)
Próba połączenia z 127.0.0.1/25...połączono.
fetchmail: SMTP< 220 mail.domain.pl - Welcome to Qmail ESMTP
fetchmail: SMTP> EHLO domain.pl
fetchmail: SMTP< 250-mail.domain.pl - Welcome to Qmail
fetchmail: SMTP< 250-STARTTLS
fetchmail: SMTP< 250-PIPELINING
fetchmail: SMTP< 250-8BITMIME
fetchmail: SMTP< 250-SIZE 268435456
fetchmail: SMTP< 250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
fetchmail: SMTP> MAIL FROM:<myincorrectemail@wp.pl> SIZE=3261
fetchmail: SMTP< 250 Refused. You have no reverse DNS entry.
fetchmail: SMTP> RCPT TO:<admin@domain.pl>
fetchmail: SMTP< 421 Refused. You have no reverse DNS entry.
fetchmail: błąd SMTP: 421 Refused. You have no reverse DNS entry.
fetchmail: SMTP> RSET
fetchmail: SMTP< 554 Refused. You have no reverse DNS entry.
. nie został skasowany
fetchmail: POP3> QUIT
fetchmail: POP3< +OK core-doe004a.r1000.mail.aol.com closing connection
fetchmail: SMTP> QUIT
fetchmail: SMTP< 221 Refused. You have no reverse DNS entry.
fetchmail: 6.3.6 łączy się z pop.aol.com (protokół POP3) o godzinie sob 26 sty 2013 00:02:36 CET: odpytywanie zakończone
fetchmail: praca zakończona poprawnie, kod wyjścia 0
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a look into your fetchmail configuration?

Comment: Here you are: `set postmaster someuser@aol.pl
poll pop.aol.com
proto pop3
port 995
user someuser@aol.pl
password mypassword
is admin@somedomain.pl
ssl
fetchall
nokeep
no rewrite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - there should be smtphost specified:

```
set postmaster
someuser@aol.pl
poll pop.aol.com
proto pop3 port 995
user someuser@aol.pl
password mypassword
smtphost somedomain.pl
is admin@somedomain.pl
ssl
fetchall
nokeep
no rewrite
```